# Как изменить текущую позицию (текущий кадр) CSS-анимации через JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Как известно, CSS-анимации создаются через `@keyframes`, и ключевые кадры там задаются в процентах. Так вот, как установить элементу конкретный процент, который должен отображаться? Сама анимация при этом должна быть приостановлена, просто должен отображаться выбранный скриптом кадр.

Зачем это нужно: например, пользователь возюкает пальцем по экрану своего айфончика, и в зависимости от положения пальца нужно изменить положение и вид какого-нибудь элемента (свайп со сложной анимацией, например). Ну или произвольная анимация перелистывания слайдов в слайдере тем же пальцем.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проценты установить нельзя, но, если знать длительность анимации (`animation-duration`), можно пересчитать проценты в секунды и установить отрицательный `animation-delay`, так, чтобы анимация как бы начиналась с указанной секунды. Например, если длина анимации `3s` и нам нужен кадр `50%`, то ставим `animation-delay: -1.5s` (середина анимации).

Чтобы это нормально работало, нужно соблюсти ещё несколько условий:

- `animation-iteration-count: 1` и `animation-fill-mode: forwards` — это нужно для того, чтобы при >=100% отображался последний кадр анимации (если это не указать, то при 100% отобразится первый кадр)
- `animation-play-state: paused`, чтобы анимация полностью контролировалась скриптом и не воспроизводилась сама по себе.

Всё это можно объединить в одном CSS-свойстве `animation` для краткости.

Пример:

```js
var anim = document.getElementById('anim');
var rng = document.getElementById('rng');

function setAnimPercent(percent) {
  var duration = 2;  // длительность знаем заранее
  var frac = parseFloat(percent) / 100.0;
  var seconds = duration * frac;
  anim.style.animationDelay = '-' + seconds + 's';
};

rng.onchange = rng.oninput = function() {
  setAnimPercent(rng.value);
};
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
  from {
    background: green;
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
    border-radius: 0%;
  }
  to {
    background: red;
    transform: translateX(300px) rotate(45deg);
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}

#anim {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  animation: anim 2s paused forwards linear;
}

#rng {
  width: 310px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="anim"></div><br/>
Укажите процент:<br/>
<input type="range" id="rng" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
```